# Travis-CI - chrome 62 instead of 77

Tags: travis-ci

For two days Travis CI returns version 62 of chrome instead of 77, do you also have the problem on your CI / CD?

**.travis.yml** ([source](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/.travis.yml))

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
```

**trace:** ([source](https://travis-ci.org/NoraUi/NoraUi/jobs/583724920))

```
$ export CHROME_SOURCE_URL=https://dl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Installing Google Chrome stable
1.17s$ wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/$(basename $CHROME_SOURCE_URL) $CHROME_SOURCE_URL
2019-09-11 15:41:31 URL:https://dl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb [62302944/62302944] -> "/tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" [1]
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add install `dpkg`

**.travis.yml:**

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - dpkg
  chrome: stable
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug with the dpkg package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627) not supporting xz compressed packages and latest versions of Chrome apparently use it.

The best solution would be to upgrade to [`dist: xenial` build env](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/xenial/) since trusty are quire old now. Or update the package I guess.

See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9361

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Linux distribution fixed the issue for me.

Change:

```
dust: trusty
```

To:

```
dist: xenial
```

In the `.travis.yml` file, change my Chrome version from `62.0.3202.94` to `81.0.4044.138`

Comment: it saves my life

```
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (83.0.4103.106-1) over (73.0.3683.86-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (83.0.4103.106-1) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on our opensource project by forcing dpkg reinstall:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/15581